# Two Dimensional Array need to display in textarea and 4 radio buttons

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

I have here an array which I need to display on the textarea which is the question and on 4 radio buttons which are the answer. I combined the question and answers in one array so the first one is the question and the remaining are the answers. I'm having problem displaying the questions in textarea, but the answers correctly display on the radio button. I think I'm having a problem on the loop. Any idea on this?

```
<?php
$question = array(

            array("What is the center of the universe?", "Sun", "Moon", "Jupiter", "Venus"),
            array("What is your name?", "Me", "Nothing", "Awesome", "Genuis")
    );

?>

<div id="wrapper"> 

<?php 
    for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
    {
        ?> <textarea name="question1" style="width:500px; height:100px"><? echo  $question[$i] ?></textarea> <?

        for($j=1; $j<5; $j++)
        {   

?>  


            <div id="answers"> 
                <table style="width:500px"> 
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="question1"><? echo $question[$i][$j] ?></td>

                </tr>

                </table>

            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is the first element of the inner array. You were echoing the whole array, which couldn't work (or echo "Array").

```
<?php echo $question[$i][0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've already choosen an answer, but let me share this one with you. It's a full solution, using `foreach`. The advantage of this, that it would work with any number of questions and answers. You could have a questions with 2 answers only, or with 10 different answers as well (or with any other answers).

```
<?php
  $questions = array(
    array("What is the center of the universe?", "Sun", "Moon", "Jupiter", "Venus"),
    array("What is your name?", "Me", "Nothing", "Awesome", "Genuis"),
    array("Are you smart?", "Yes", "No"),
    array("On a scale of 1 to 10, how hungry are you?", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
  );
?>

<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <?php foreach($questions as $qkey => $question) { ?>
      <label>Question <?php echo $qkey+1; ?>:<br />
        <textarea name="question_array[<?php echo $qkey+1; ?>]" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;"><?php echo $question[0]; ?></textarea>
      </label><br />
      <?php foreach ($question as $key => $value) { ?>
        <?php if ($key != 0) { ?> 
          <input type="radio" name="answer_array[<?php echo $qkey+1; ?>]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="answer<?php echo $qkey; ?>_<?php echo $key; ?>" required />
          <label for="answer<?php echo $qkey; ?>_<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></label><br />
        <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
      <br />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit my answers" />
  </form>
<?php } else { ?>
  <pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>
<?php } ?>
```

Working PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3q01-w4uk